# rails json posted as hash instead of array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json

I am having some problems with an ajax post to a ROR action (from one server to another). Basically, this request:

```
post_json = { "stuff": [{"1" => "foo"}] };

$.ajax({
  url: "http://someurl.com/api/random_post_action",
  type: "post",
  dataType: "json",
  data: post_json,
  success: function(data){
    console.log(data);
}});
```

Gives in the random_post_action params (ruby on rails):

```
{
  "stuff" => {
    "0" => {
        "1" => "foo"
    }
  },
  "controller" => "api",
  "action" => "random_post_action"
}
```

What is expected:

```
{
  "stuff" => [
    [0] {
          "1" => "foo"
        }
  ],
  "controller" => "api",
  "action" => "random_post_action"
}
```

I am not sure what is going on...

Comment: you're expecting invalid json?  what your post_json equates to should be `{ "stuff"=> [{"1"}, {"foo"}] }` as it states.. `{"1"}` and `{"foo"}` are completely seperate objects.. if you want 1 => foo, then you need `.. [{"1": "foo"}]`

Comment: @sircapsalot Sorry it was a typo when I wrote the question above. The question still holds.

Comment: "The question still holds"? What question? I see statements but no question asked. Perhaps you meant to ask something like "Why is "stuff" a hash-of-hashes instead of an array of hashes?"

Comment: @theTinMan Sorry if that was not clear but your answer is pretty harsh. I have stated what I got and what I expected and I thought the problem was pretty clear. Perhaps you can answer my question as to why I am getting a hash instead of an array? That would be more constructive.